# Write "null" if column doesn't exist with KeyError: "['Column'] not in index" in df.to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am getting `KeyError: "['CashFinancial'] not in index"` on the `df.to_csv` line because 'GOOG' doesn't have the `CashFinancial` column.  How can I have it write in `null` for the `CashFinancial` value for 'GOOG'?

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT'] #This will be 75,000 symbols.
header = ["asOfDate","CashAndCashEquivalents","CashFinancial","CurrentAssets","TangibleBookValue","CurrentLiabilities","TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest"]

for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.balance_sheet(frequency='q')
    df = faang.balance_sheet(frequency='q')
    df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```py
if tick == "GOOG"
    df.loc[:,"CashFinancial"] = None
```

To set an entire `CashFinancial` column to "None" only if your "tick" was `GOOG`, before writing it to csv.

The full code from the example you posted would he something like :

```py
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT']
header = ["asOfDate","CashAndCashEquivalents","CashFinancial","CurrentAssets","TangibleBookValue","CurrentLiabilities","TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest"]

for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.balance_sheet(frequency='q')
    df = faang.balance_sheet(frequency='q')#,{"symbol":[1],"asOfDate":[2],"CashAndCashEquivalents":[3],"CashFinancial":[4],"CurrentAssets":[5],"TangibleBookValue":[6],"CurrentLiabilities":[7],"TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest":[8],"marketCap":[9]}
    for column_name in header :
        if not column_name in df.columns :
            #Here, if any column is missing from the names you defined 
            #in your "header" variable, we add this column and set all 
            #it's row values to None
            df.loc[:,column_name  ] = None
    
    df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Osamoele, but I've got 30,000 symbols, so can't write that many ifs.

Comment: Ok, Then i added a programmatic way to check is any column is missing for any tick. Check my edit

Comment: Thank you, Osamoele :).  I am getting `TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable` when I run it.

Comment: Sorry i made a typo writing columns (and it is a property, not a method, so no need for parenthesis, my bad) The edit shoud work ( `df.columns` instead of `df.columsn()` )

Comment: Some tickers don't exist in Yahoo Finance (or have changed/been deleted).  I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'` for those tickers such as `'015.F'`.  Any idea how to skip those?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the handling of expected exceptions thrown in python. For example at : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp You could easily implement a quick checker when creating the faang variable such that it is encapsulated inside an except statement : `try: faag = Ticker(tick) except AttributeError : continue` . I assume you know what `continue` does in a for loop. But overall I suggest you take free tutorial courses online (there are plenty) for python if you'd like to gain this knowledge. It's realy some basic stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much, Osamoele.  That's just what I did (`try` `except` `continue`).  Works great.  Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Load all dataframes into a list, then use `pd.concat` (it will create NaN in missing columns):

```py
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker

symbols = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"]
header = [
    "asOfDate",
    "CashAndCashEquivalents",
    "CashFinancial",
    "CurrentAssets",
    "TangibleBookValue",
    "CurrentLiabilities",
    "TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest",
]

all_dfs = []
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    df = faang.balance_sheet(frequency="q")
    all_dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(all_dfs)

for symbol, g in df.groupby(level=0):
    print(symbol)
    print(g[header])
    # to save to CSV:
    # g[header].to_csv('filename.csv')
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
AAPL
         asOfDate  CashAndCashEquivalents  CashFinancial  CurrentAssets  TangibleBookValue  CurrentLiabilities  TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest
symbol                                                                                                                                             
AAPL   2021-09-30            3.494000e+10   1.730500e+10   1.348360e+11       6.309000e+10        1.254810e+11                         2.879120e+11
AAPL   2021-12-31            3.711900e+10   1.799200e+10   1.531540e+11       7.193200e+10        1.475740e+11                         3.092590e+11
AAPL   2022-03-31            2.809800e+10   1.429800e+10   1.181800e+11       6.739900e+10        1.275080e+11                         2.832630e+11
AAPL   2022-06-30            2.750200e+10   1.285200e+10   1.122920e+11       5.810700e+10        1.298730e+11                         2.782020e+11
AAPL   2022-09-30            2.364600e+10   1.854600e+10   1.354050e+11       5.067200e+10        1.539820e+11                         3.020830e+11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GOOG
         asOfDate  CashAndCashEquivalents  CashFinancial  CurrentAssets  TangibleBookValue  CurrentLiabilities  TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest
symbol                                                                                                                                             
GOOG   2021-09-30            2.371900e+10            NaN   1.841100e+11       2.203950e+11        6.178200e+10                         1.028360e+11
GOOG   2021-12-31            2.094500e+10            NaN   1.881430e+11       2.272620e+11        6.425400e+10                         1.076330e+11
GOOG   2022-03-31            2.088600e+10            NaN   1.778530e+11       2.296810e+11        6.194800e+10                         1.030920e+11
GOOG   2022-06-30            1.793600e+10            NaN   1.723710e+11       2.300930e+11        6.135400e+10                         9.976600e+10
GOOG   2022-09-30            2.198400e+10            NaN   1.661090e+11       2.226000e+11        6.597900e+10                         1.046290e+11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSFT
         asOfDate  CashAndCashEquivalents  CashFinancial  CurrentAssets  TangibleBookValue  CurrentLiabilities  TotalLiabilitiesNetMinorityInterest
symbol                                                                                                                                             
MSFT   2021-09-30            1.916500e+10   6.863000e+09   1.743260e+11       9.372900e+10        8.052800e+10                         1.834400e+11
MSFT   2021-12-31            2.060400e+10   6.255000e+09   1.741880e+11       1.016270e+11        7.751000e+10                         1.803790e+11
MSFT   2022-03-31            1.249800e+10   7.456000e+09   1.539220e+11       8.420500e+10        7.743900e+10                         1.816830e+11
MSFT   2022-06-30            1.393100e+10   8.258000e+09   1.696840e+11       8.772000e+10        9.508200e+10                         1.982980e+11
MSFT   2022-09-30            2.288400e+10   7.237000e+09   1.608120e+11       9.529900e+10        8.738900e+10                         1.862180e+11
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrej Kesely!  But when I write to csv, it only outputs MSFT.  Also, I need it to write to csv one at a time as I have 75,000 symbols to write to csv, and my connection might fail during the hours it takes to write them all.